# Can I use ARWorld map together with roomCaptureView?

Tags: swift, arkit, roomplan

Does anybody know if I can use the ARWorld map together with roomCaptureView? So that I can scan and save one Room, then save the data from scan, save the ARWorldmap and then make a new roomCaptureView.captureSession to scan the new room?
I am trying to make a floorpan using RoomPlan API.

Right know I am first calling:
 roomCaptureView?.captureSession.run(configuration: roomCaptureSessionConfig)
to get the captureSession started
and then
roomCaptureView.captureSession.arSession.run(roomCaptureViewARconfigurationFunc)
with the saved ARWorldMap to update the world map.

```
@IBAction func saveWorldMapAction(_ sender: Any) {
        roomCaptureView.captureSession.arSession.getCurrentWorldMap { worldMap, error in
            guard let map = worldMap
            else { self.worldMapLabel.text = "error \(error!.localizedDescription) "; return }
            
do {
                let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: map, requiringSecureCoding: true)
                try data.write(to: self.mapSaveURL, options: [.atomic])
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.loadWordMapButton.isHidden = false
                    self.loadWordMapButton.isEnabled = true
                    self.worldMapLabel.text = "Map Saved "
                    print(" map saved")
                }
            } catch {
                fatalError("Can't save map: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
```

```
@IBAction func AddNewRoomBtnPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

        sceneViewFloorPlan.alpha = 0

        stopSession()

        startSession()

        oadWordMap()
}
```

```
private func startSession() {

        isScanning = true

        print("start roomCaptureView")

        roomCaptureView?.captureSession.run(configuration: roomCaptureSessionConfig)

        setActiveNavBar()

    }
```

```
var defaultConfiguration: ARWorldTrackingConfiguration {

    let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()

    configuration.environmentTexturing = .none

    return configuration

}

func loadWordMap(){
    let worldMap: ARWorldMap = {
        guard let data = mapDataFromFile
            else { fatalError("Map data should already be verified to exist before Load button is enabled.") }

        do {
            guard let worldMap = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: ARWorldMap.self, from: data)
                else { fatalError("No ARWorldMap in archive.") }
            return worldMap
        } catch {
            fatalError("Can't unarchive ARWorldMap from file data: \(error)")
        }
    }()

    let configuration = self.defaultConfiguration // this app's standard world tracking settings
    configuration.initialWorldMap = worldMap
    guard let roomCaptureViewARconfigurationFunc = roomCaptureView.captureSession.arSession.configuration else {
        return }
    isScanning = true    roomCaptureView.captureSession.arSession.run(roomCaptureViewARconfigurationFunc)
setActiveNavBar()
}
```